# jQuery hidden Selector does not work properly in IE 11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, selector, hidden

I have a problem with the jQuery hidden selector in IE.

The following syntax returns true always on IE 11:

```
$(someElement).is(":hidden")
```

As a simple example you can try this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/1ox8q5x2/7/

This works fine under Firefox, but not under IE 11.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Its working fine under IE11. I checked out your fiddle.See if your security or privacy settings are not affecting the script execution.

Comment: FYI I tried this on IE10 and it shows your popup which says "This popup should never show up!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that :visible & :hidden both are displaying incorrect values for IE11. You can try below code, I have tested it and it is working on all browser

```
$(".pagination li").on("click", function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.show();
    if (elem[0].style.display == 'none') {
        alert("This Popup should never show up!");
    }
    elem.hide();
    if (elem[0].style.display == 'none') {
        alert("The element is hidden!");
    }
    setTimeout(function () { elem.show(); }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: This is an easy to use workaround. I still don't understand though, why IE11 behaves this way. Thx for the quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to only affect `li` elements, a `button` element with similar code correctly reports its state using `:hidden` selector

http://jsfiddle.net/e08u8z0f/